# Backing up Adobe CS6, Microsoft office, Camtasia on Time Machine - will they completely restore?

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine, backup, ms-office, adobe

I have a hard drive problem. If I use Time machine to make regular backups, will Adobe CS6, Microsoft office, Camtasia and other installed programmes completely retore on a new hard drive without any complications? I have been told various things that seem to conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Office 2011 will work fine after restoring from Time Machine, but Outlook will generate a new Database.